# Can't select a child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this HTML:

```
                <ul>
                <a href="#"><li>Test</li></a>
                <a href="#"><li>Test2</li></a>
                <a href="#" class="with-sub"><li>Test3</li>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </ul>
```

And jQuery:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".sub").hide();
    });
    $(".with-sub").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub").slideDown( "slow", function() {

        });
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the link with "with-sub" class nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your html and jquery to following:

```js
$(".with-sub").click(function() {
  $(this).next("ul").slideDown();
});
```

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Test</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Test2</li>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="with-sub">
    <li>Test3
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub3</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

As mention in comments your html is not correct. `ul` elements can contain zero or more `li` elements, eventually mixed with `ol` and `ul` elements.

```js
$(".with-sub").click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul").toggle();
});
```

```css
.sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Test2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="with-sub"><a href="#">Test3</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sub3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @MuchaZ Glad that I helped you. If this answer solved your problem please don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: Yeah, sure. I can do it in 3 minutes.

Comment: @AlexChar Not my downvote, but I can explain: because you didn't fix invalid HTML like if it was fine, however it's not.

Comment: @dfsq Added an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Your current code does not work because you are attempting to bind an event to elements that do not exist in the DOM yet - you need to put the `click()` handler inside the DOMReady handler.

Also note that your HTML is invalid - only `li` elements can be direct descendants of the `ul` element. Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Test2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="with-sub">Test3</a>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sub3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Once you've fixed your HTML, the following jQuery will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub").hide();
    $(".with-sub").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings(".sub").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmo3acqg/)

Comment: And I'll also recommend `.sub { display: none; }` in CSS

Comment: @MuchaZ Did you also fix HTML?